# Cannot compile ReactJS code without "Parsing error" error

Tags: reactjs

New to Reactjs and am trying to setup my first app. Used Facebook's Create React App and am following a tutorial I found on YouTube.

As soon as I import 'Nav' component and add the nave bar code I get an error that says"line 15:7:  Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Nav.item>" The error is pointing to the closing Nav tag. I have tried different variations of Nav code but nothing seems to work.

**Code without Nav component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {  } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**Code with Nav compenent:**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav fill variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home">
        <Nav.item>
          <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      <Nav fill variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home">
        <Nav.item>
          <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.item> <-------- you just missed this
      </Nav>
```

Comment: Line 15:9:  Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Nav.item>


  13 |         <Nav.item>
  14 |           <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
> 15 |         </Nav.Item>
     |         ^
  16 |       </Nav>

Comment: @JonathanNiess maybe the last `>` is extra in: `<Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link> >`  . remove it.